# Texture2D.LoadImage() with EmguCV on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, emgucv, texture2d

I am using the Capture class from EmguCV to put the image from the camera on a Texture2D using LoadImage function. Before trying to do this, i was using the SetPixel function but it was too slow.

When I execute the code below, a red question mark on a white background appears instead of the image of the camera.

What am I doing wrong here ?

```
public class testEmguCV : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Capture capture;

    void Start() 
    {
        capture = new Capture();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Image<Gray, Byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryGrayFrame();
        Texture2D camera = new Texture2D(400, 400);
        if (currentFrame != null)
        {
            camera.LoadImage(currentFrame.Bytes);
            renderer.material.mainTexture = camera;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: From a quick search, LoadImage appears to be made for converting Jpgs and Pngs into a Texture2d. Given that you're using the emgu image class, I doubt that's going to work... Perhaps save the image into a memorystream as a jpg, then throw that into the LoadImage?

Comment: Thank you Steven, I did that and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the modifications I did to correct the problem:

```
public class testEmguCV : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Capture capture;

    void Start() 
    {
        capture = new Capture();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Image<Gray, Byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryGrayFrame();
        Bitmap bitmapCurrentFrame = currentFrame.ToBitmap();
        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
        bitmapCurrentFrame.Save(m, bitmapCurrentFrame.RawFormat);

        Texture2D camera = new Texture2D(400, 400);
        if (currentFrame != null)
        {
            camera.LoadImage(m.ToArray());
            renderer.material.mainTexture = camera;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I am having this error when using your code. Any insight?     ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: encoder
System.Drawing.Image.Save (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo encoder, System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters encoderParams)
System.Drawing.Image.Save (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Image:Save (System.IO.Stream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat)
Script.Update () (at Assets/Script.cs:61)

Comment: I solved the problem when using system.drawing.dll from Unity installation folder.